# jQuery How to check if the current position of a div is equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck. I am working on a jQuery game and I need to know the current position of a object and check if it equals to 0. I tried different things but none of them worked. Here is the code:

```
function movePoint() {
   $( '.point' ).each( function() {
       if($(this).attr('id').position().left == 0) {
          console.log("Yay!");
       }
       $( this ).css( 'left', $( this ).position().left - ( speed + (roundsClicked / 10) ) );
       console.log("Left position of your element - " + $(this).position().left);
   });
}
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id').position().left` should be `$(this).position().left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your code to this

```
function movePoint() {
   $( '.point' ).each( function() {
       if($(this).position().left == 0) {// if($(this).css('left') == '0px') 
          console.log("Yay!");
       }
       $( this ).css( 'left', $( this ).position().left - ( speed + (roundsClicked / 10) ) );
       console.log("Left position of your element - " + $(this).position().left);
   });
}
```

Comment: The line: if($(this).css('left') == '0px') works! :)
Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm weird.. First it worked. But now not. How? It looks like the object goes to fast and skips the position 0. Can this be the problem?

Comment: can you please make a fiddle ?

Comment: check this console http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/nwn2g8jn/7/ the value is never equal zero use `<= ` and not `==`   working demo http://jsfiddle.net/nwn2g8jn/8

Comment: Wouw. I feel so stupid. >_>
Thank you for your time :)